# When will a local variable be killed when it holds the delegate references?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I don't really understand the memory management in delegate pattern.

In the Controller, if it **owns** that object. we should assign a strong pointer to it.
So that the object it **owns** will not lose.

I have created a small library class to help me do async connection, it holds a weak pointer to the ViewController which adopts its protocol. When the connection is finished, the data is sent back to the ViewController.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol AsyncConnectionDelegate;

@interface AsyncConnection : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <AsyncConnectionDelegate> delegate;

-(void)callAsyncConnectionAtUrl:(NSString *)url dictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary method:(NSString *)method delegate:(id)delegate;
@end

@protocol AsyncConnectionDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)finishConnectionWithData:(NSData *)data connection:(AsyncConnection *)connection;
@end
```

**Usage:** (When the button pressed)

```
// user input
NSString *username = _usernameTextField.text;
NSString *password = _pwdTextField.text;

//create dictionary key-value pair for transformming into NSData
NSMutableDictionary *loginKeyValue = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[loginKeyValue setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
[loginKeyValue setObject:password forKey:@"password"];


AsyncConnection *conc = [[AsyncConnection alloc]init];
[conc callAsyncConnectionAtUrl:@"http://localhost:3000/login.json" dictionary:loginKeyValue method:@"POST" delegate:self];
```

The `*conc` here is only a local variables, the view controller **did not holds a strong  reference** to it. So in my point of view, it supposed to be killed when the method is finished executing. However, it can be alive and sending back the data to the ViewController.

**Delegate method**

```
- (void)finishConnectionWithData:(NSData *)data connection:(AsyncConnection *)connection{

    NSLog(@"Connection Object : %@", connection );

    Member *member = [Member initWithData:data];
    NSLog(@"member username \n %@",member.username);
    NSLog(@"member password \n %@",member.password);

    NSString *msg = (member.username)?@"Login Success":@"Failed to login";

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"NOTICE!!" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

**The class just use this method to send back the data:
It is the delegate method of NSURLConnection:**

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    [_delegate finishConnectionWithData:_downloadData connection:self];   
}
```

I tried to log the memory address of the connection object out twice, they are different.
(I kicked the button twice ) . So I wonder when the connection object will be killed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior depends on the implementation of `-[AsyncConnection callAsyncConnectionAtUrl:dictionary:method:delegate:]`.

If it did nothing at all, then you're correct, you would expect the `AsyncConnection *conc` to be deallocated at the end of the button-pressed method, since nobody else would retain it.

However, `-callAsyncConnectionAtUrl:` probably does something that causes `self` to be retained for a while. (Does it pass `self` to some other code that might retain it? Or does it contain a block that references `self`, and then passes that block to some other code?)

If you want to know when the `AsyncConnection` gets deallocated in practice, it's easy to find out: add an implementation of `dealloc` to `AsyncConnection`, set a breakpoint in it, and run your code.

Comment: It only do `_delegate = delegate;`. I tried your advice which is to add `deadlloc` into the class. The result is surprised. The object will be deallocated after the delegate method of NSURLConnection. I will edit my question :)

Comment: tick for the first answer :)

Answer (score 1):

By the name of the object, it probably creates an NSURLConnection and sets itself as the delegate. From the documentation for NSURLConnection:

> Special Considerations
>
> During the download the connection maintains a strong reference to the delegate. It releases that strong reference when the connection finishes loading, fails, or is canceled.

So there is a mini (intentional) retain cycle keeping your AsycConnection object alive.

Comment: Your guess is right :) It will create a NSURLConnection. At the end. The NSURLConnection releases the AsycConnection object. That's why I find my AsycConnection Object will deallocated when the connection finishes loading. :)

Comment: So, is there anything else you need to know, or have Kurt and I answered your question?

Comment: your answer is great,too :)

Comment: Kurt's was better, mine just filled in a blank.